# How to get correct easter_date()

Tags: php

For some odd reason, when I try the PHP easter_date() function, it doesn't quite work like I want.  I want it to show today is Easter.  However, when I was doing a printout of the date, it was showing it about a day ahead.   I think it's possible that it's using a different timezone (other than localhost) to get it.   It was showing that it was Easter around midnight (which it should be), but now that it is noon, it is not.

[code]

```
$greetingString = "Greeting";
.......

$theYear = date('Y');



 $eDay = date('d', easter_date($theYear));


$eMonth = date('n', easter_date($theYear));


if ($month == $eMonth && $day == $eDay)
$greetingString = "Happy Easter";

......


<h1>Welcome &amp; <?php echo $greetingString; ?></h1>
```

[/code]

It  is supposed to say Welcome & Happy Easter, but it is saying Welcome & Greeting.

It WAS working earlier today, but now it's not, so I think it might be some kind of time zone issue.

Comment: Make sure your timezone is set correctly with [`date_deault_timezone_set()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: The default time zone should be the same one as my computer, which is central time.

Comment: The php function page says: Note:
easter_date() relies on your system's C library time functions, rather than using PHP's internal date and time functions. As a consequence, easter_date() uses the TZ environment variable to determine the time zone it should operate in, rather than using PHP's default time zone, which may result in unexpected behaviour when using this function in conjunction with other date functions in PHP.   So I think it's conflicting with the date() function.

Comment: The php function page also describes a workaround ;)

Comment: Heh I wonder if `strtotime("easter")` works... :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky: [No, it doesn't ;)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4816b5ad16dd98bfca4fc10cc54d3c28c99cb980)

Comment: I told it echo date("M-d-Y",easter_date(2017));  It outputted Apr-15-2017.   But today is April-16-2017.

Comment: The so-called workaround function on the PHP easter_date() page isn't working either.  It gave me 2017-05-07 12:22:47  Which appears to be May 7, 2017  12:22:47

Comment: Thanks for the PHP sandbox.  I was looking for something like that.   Chrome only seems to help with JS so I never know what's wrong with my PHP code.

Comment: Adding +1 to the date value makes it "work" now, but I don't think it was working when it had the +1 in there when I ran it at midnight.

Comment: I got to thinking of something, and this might explain it:  Perhaps it is a day off because it goes on GMT or something (at least for the day).   However, is it also not using Daylight Savings Time (1 hour ahead)?  If so, then it would still be thinking it was the day before Easter until 1:00 my time.